# Su is not working

Tags: terminal, sudo, su

When I type su in terminal nothing happens. Literally nothing. Not even sudo su. It just gives me another line. What do I do?

Comment: were you already root?

Comment: um i don't know i am new to this

Answer (score 4):

Are you already logged in as root?

Run the command:

```
whoami
```

to know which user you are currently "using."

If you are already root, you don't need to use `su`.

Comment: it sais root . so i don't need to execute su?

Comment: No. You use the "su" command in order to gain access to the root shell. If you already are root, you don't need to execute su. Same applies to sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

'su' allows you to switch to another user ,and if you do not run it with any parameter it thiks you want to become root. You can use 'su' to switch to another user too .Just do a 'su username' and you will switch to that username.If you are not root , and you run 'su' it will ask you for root password , but if you are alraedy root ,you will see like you said , just a new line , because it dnt ask you for root passwod if you are already root
It depends on what linux version you have , me as a Lnux Mint user I do not use 'su' to become root , me  I use the 'sudo' command.
if i run 'sudo -s' it will ask me for root password and after  I enter the root password , I will have a root shell.